# Importing huge records from Excel to MsAccess - Subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a very large number of rows (220,000) and 30 columns in an Excel (2007) file, which I am trying to import to some databases either MsAccess for some reports.

I tried to do programming using Visual Basic 6.0 to read from Excel and insert in msAccess but it's taking too much time (around 4-5 hours, which is no use).

Next I tried to import to MsAccess using the import wizard, it shows "Subscript out of range" error at the end of the wizard.

Comment: Can you clarify the number 2,20,000 please?

Comment: Yes it is 2,20,000 records and 30 Columns in excel 2007 format. As you suggested I need to break the excelsheet instead of msAccess table which works fine. But that is time taking task

Comment: 2,20,000 isn't a valid number - is it 2,200,000 or 200,000?

Comment: @Widor it's in [lakhs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Comment: @Boud [I should have known](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108418/which-common-english-language-errors-and-idioms-make-so-questions-tough-to-read/108434#108434)! Updated (correctly, I hope) as SO is an English-language site.

Comment: Just how big is each row of this Excel file? What are these 30 columns? Numbers, text?

Comment: @CodeSlave It is combination of text, numbers and even dates.

Comment: I concur with Widor. Find a way to make it smaller. Or you could upgrade to a more robust DB (sql server or MS Access 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to figure out the issue with ADO using Visual Basic instead of Excel cell reading. Which is much faster (around 2-3 minutes for all the records).

I just created a name range and through ODBC I accessed using ADO as records and inserted same in MySQL.
It solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're exceeding one of the limits imposed in an Access database:

[Access Blog - Access 2007 Limits](http://web.archive.org/web/20130525073743/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2006/06/05/access-2007-limits.aspx)

Perhaps you could narrow down the problem by creating several tables with identical columns, then import chunks of the data so you don't have an all-or-nothing scenario.

Then, you'll either be able to narrow down the source of the error or, if it works, merge the tables into one.

Comment: No the limit is not under the criteria mentioned above. It is around 50MB thats why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, so I'm adding this in case anyone else runs into it.

Copy network files to your local drive, both DB and excel.